# How can you shorten validation in Vue?

Tags: vue.js

How can you shorten validation in Vue?

```html
<template 
  v-if="editedItem.arrayImages4 && editedItem.arrayImages4.length > 0"
></template>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing too fancy that you can do here, maybe use `computed` + some [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) like this (you can't do this in the template unfortunately)

```html
<template v-if="doItemContainImages"></template>
```

```js
computed: {
  doItemContainImages() {
    return editedItem?.arrayImages4?.length
  },
},
```